# Difference between DataView.Sort and DataTable.DefaultView.Sort ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, datatable

am Using `DataTable` in `C# asp.net` project. I want to apply `sorting` on `DataTable`.

- I got the two way to do this as below.

  1. Using **`DefaultView`**

`DataTable dt= GetDataFromDB(); // Method to fetch Data. 
        dt.DefaultView.Sort = "colName" + " " + "ASC";
        dt= dt.DefaultView.ToTable();`

2. Using **`DataView.Sort`**

`DataView sortedView = new DataView(ViewState["dt"] as DataTable);
                sortedView.Sort = "colName" + " " + "ASC";
// ViewState["dt"] is defined in Page_Load event in my Page.`

- Both are working fine for me, **But I want to know the difference between them and which one is better as far as performance concern.**
- **Note: I am dealing with Large Data amount.**(40000-60000 records.)

Comment: There's very little difference: The first acess to the DefaultView property will create a DataView on demand.  Storing a large DataTable in ViewState will likely have a much bigger impact on performance.

Comment: @Joe - but which one with I should go? `DataTable` or `DataView` because in 2nd Way - I have to casting `DataTable to DataView` or `ViewState[] to DataTable`.

Answer (score 0):

The DataTable.DefaultView property provides an instance of the DataView class on demand. So performance-wise they are the same.

The main problem with the sample code in your question is storing the DataTable in the ViewState, which will cause performance problems if the size of the DataTable is large.

Also, you can always bind your controls to the DataView as

```cs
dt= dt.DefaultView.ToTable();
```

will duplicate the table in memory as it will create a new table to provide the sorted data .. causing more memory usage!

Answer (score 0):

I think that creating a new DataView is better but not in the way you did it. 
DataView creates the index, by default it will be probably the ID of the item. When you change Sort property, the new index is created. So when you use DefaultView and use Sort property the code needs to create 2 indexes. When you use an overloaded constructor of DataView in which you can state the Sort query you will create only single index: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/8sd1cd0a(v=vs.110).aspx